# Spring Boot Security module gives 403 error when called by using axios from react but works fine in postman

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, axios, jwt

I have a spring boot project that uses spring security with JWT token. This works fine in POSTMAN but it gives a 403 error when using react axios.
Below is the code used

SecurityConfig.java

```
    package com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.config;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
    
    import com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.Service.CustomUserService;
    import com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.filter.EmployeeCRUDFilter;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        CustomUserService userService;
        
        @Autowired
        EmployeeCRUDFilter employeeCRUDFilter;
        
        /*
         * @Autowired CorsFilter corsFilter;
         */
    
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hi1");
            auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
    
            @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)  {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hi2");
              try { 
                  CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
                  
                  http
                 // .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class) 
                  .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate/")
                  .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                  .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                  .and().cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration);
    ;
          http.addFilterBefore(employeeCRUDFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                  } 
              catch (Exception e) 
              { 
                      // TODO: handle exception 
                      e.printStackTrace(); 
                      }
                  }
             
        }
```

EmployeeCRUDFilter.java

```
package com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.Service.CustomUserService;
import com.cg.practice.EmployeeCRUD.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;

@Component
public class EmployeeCRUDFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    CustomUserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String token = null;
        String userName = null;
try
{
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
        }

        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }   
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
            }
    }
```

CRUDController method

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    
    public String generateToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception
    {

        try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authRequest.getUserName(),authRequest.getPassword())        
                        );
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "Invalid User/Password";
        }
        return jwtUtil.generateToken(authRequest.getUserName());
    }
```

React Authservice.js

```
import http from '../Mycomponent/http-common';

class AuthService{

    authenticate(){
        return http.post("/authenticate", {"userName":"Dip","password":"password@123"}
        )
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            if (response.data.accessToken) {
              localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }
            return response.data;
          })
          .catch(error =>{
            console.log("Error :"+error);
          });
    }
}
export default new AuthService();
```

http-common.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/CRUD",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
      }
});
```

This gives a 403 error in browser

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
AuthService.js:16 Error :Error: Request failed with status code 403
:8080/CRUD/getAll:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

Can anyone please help. I am stuck on it for a long time. Am I missing something? I am new to react.

Works fine in PostMAN

Comment: You don't seem to be sending any credentials with the axios request. Shouldn't you be setting the Authorization header? Or are you using some middleware that is supposed to do that?

Comment: authenticate(){
        return http.post("/authenticate", {"userName":"Dip","password":"password@123"}
        )
I am doing this her. Is it some mistake I am making?

Comment: Does the request to `/authenticate` return 403 or the request to `/CRUD`?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/CRUD/authenticate returns 403. It is not hitting the server backend

Comment: In the security configuration, you define `/authenticate` as the only route with anonymous access. I think this should be `/CRUD/authenticate`, if that's what you're calling to log in.

Comment: See the base URL has CRUD included. Any problem you see in CORS in server side?

Comment: Note that Spring Security has build in support for JWT authentication, so there is no need to create your own. You can check out a sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login).

Comment: while using postman I can connec and get this jwt token but from react I am getting this cors error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here lies the problem:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate/")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration);
```

You tell spring to `permitAll` requests to the `/authenticate/` endpoint, and require authentication for all the other requests. But from the frontend you're making a request to `/CRUD/authenticate/`. That's why you get 403, because this path must be authenticated - meaning that the request must already have the `Authorization` header. I think it should work if you change the first line to this:

```java
.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/CRUD/authenticate/")
```

Comment: At the backend in Spring Boot it is forming the url as in the application.properties file I have server.servlet.contextPath=/CRUD which forms the URL as localhost:8080/CRUD/authenticate

Comment: I see. What about the trailing slash in the antMatcher. Should that be there?

Comment: Yes I missed the trailing slash in the react. It should be there in the antmatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have missed `Authorization` in the header when you setup your axios instance

Comment: authenticate(){ return http.post("/authenticate", {"userName":"Dip","password":"password@123"} ) I am doing this her. Is it some mistake I am making? – 
Can you please show an example what you mean

Comment: for the first request authenticate I am generating the jwt token so is  the Authorisation required?